# enabled a programmatically created button in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I know how to set the enable = YES/NO, a button created using a property and xib. However, how do you do the same thing to a programmatically created button from another method in the same class?

For example here is my button in the viewDidLoad:

```
UIButton *AllList = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
AllList.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 107.f, 53.5f); //set frame for button

UIImage *buttonImageFull = [UIImage imageNamed:@"allModsBtn.png"];
[AllList setBackgroundImage:buttonImageFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:AllList];

// add targets and actions
[AllList addTarget:self action:@selector(getButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
AllList.tag = 0;
```

I would like to set the enable of this button to YES or NO in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@implementation {
     UIButton *myButton;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.tag = 121;
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 107.f, 53.5f); //set frame for button

    UIImage *buttonImageFull = [UIImage imageNamed:@"allModsBtn.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];

   // add targets and actions
   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getButtons:)       
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
   myButton.tag = 0;
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {

   myButton.enabled = YES;

OR

  //In this case you dont need to define uibutton to globaly

   UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[[self view] viewWithTag:121];
   [button setEnabled:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make that button an ivar of your view controller.

```
@implementation {
    UIButton *myButton;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 107.f, 53.5f); //set frame for button

    UIImage *buttonImageFull = [UIImage imageNamed:@"allModsBtn.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];

    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getButtons:)       
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    myButton.tag = 0;
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    myButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UIButton *myButton = [self.view viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG]; // in your case is 0
[myButton setEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: And? What I purpose does exactly that.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tag other than 0 since thats the default tag for every view.

Comment: Why use tags and not ivars? I would avoid relying on tags as much as possible.

Comment: DrummerB, actually, I was going with what you purpose, but since I saw the `myButton.tag=0` I though it could be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

1) you can make it an ivar and then

```
AllList.enabled = YES;
```

or

```
[AllList setEnabled:YES];
```

2)
set a unique tag to the button

```
UIButton *AllList = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
AllList.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 107.f, 53.5f); //set frame for button
AllList.tag = kUNIQUE_TAG;
```

in the method you want to mess with the button's enabled property

```
UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:kUNIQUE_TAG];
[theButton setEnabled:YES];
```